# g++ expected ';' before return

Tags: c++, g++, return

i got the following code beacuse im trying to understand the usage of getopt_long. everything seems fine but i get "expected ';' before return". What am i missing? Thank you all.

```
int next_option;
const string short_options = "a:bcde";
const struct option long_options[] = 
{
    {"op1", 1, NULL, 'a'},
    {"op2", 1, NULL, 'b'},
    {"op3", 1, NULL, 'c'},
    {"op4", 0, NULL, 'd'},
    {"op5", 0, NULL, 'e'},
    { NULL,0, NULL, 0}
};

do
{
    next_option = getopt_long(argc,argv,short_options.c_str(),long_options,NULL);

    switch(next_option)
    {
        case 'a':
        cout <<" ";
        break;

        case 'b':
        cout <<" ";
        break;

        case 'c':
        cout <<" ";
        break;

        case 'd':
        cout <<" ";
        break;

        case 'e':
        cout <<" ";
        break;

        case '?': // invalid option
        cout <<" ";
        break;

        case -1:  //no more option
        cout <<" ";
        break;

        default:
        cout <<" ";
        break;
    }

}
while(next_option!=-1)
return 0;
```

What's the procedure i have to follow to help me resolve errors of that kind?

Comment: How is this too localized... It's not the first nor the last time someone is going to get this error.

Answer (score 7):

My crystal ball tells me you're missing a `;` before a `return`

```
while(next_option!=-1); // <--- semi-colon
return 0;
```

Comment: +1 but I want your crystal ball! LOL

Comment: Thank you very much it seems i got stuck i was looking at my code like goofy and everything seemed right. sorry i wasted everybody's time

Answer (score 6):

The error message tells you *exactly* what the problem is - you have a missing `;`.

Change:

```
while(next_option!=-1)
```

to:

```
while(next_option!=-1);
```

Answer (score 6):

You need a `;` after `while(next_option!=-1)`.

The procedure to follow is to read the error message, and then fix the thing it's warning you about (in this case, the missing semicolon).

Answer (score 6):

The do-while statement

```
do {

} while (condition);
```

needs a terminating semicolon. Just before your `return`.

Answer (score 2):

your do/while() is a statement, so you need to terminate it with a semi colon. Look for places where you may be missing them :)